# Is there any to set the visibility of xtra tree list nodes dynamically

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using xtratreelist in my application with only first level and I want to make some of the nodes visible but not all. Here is the code, but after that all the not are showing in the list

```
TreeList tr = new Treelist();

for (int x = 0; x < tr.Nodes.Count; x++)
{
    tr.Nodes[x].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [NodesIterator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1472), here is an example, and it works for me :

The data class :

```
public class Service
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

And in my form :

```
private void TreeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     treeList1.DataSource = Service.GetServices();
     treeList1.NodesIterator.DoLocalOperation(setNodeVisibility, treeList1.Nodes);
}

private void setNodeVisibility(DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode node)
{
     var service = treeList1.GetDataRecordByNode(node) as Service;
     if (service == null)
         return;

     node.Visible = service.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following links

[FindNodeByID](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FindNodeByIDtopic)

[FindNodeByFieldValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FindNodeByFieldValuetopic)

[FindNodeByKeyID](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FindNodeByKeyIDtopic)

Comment: I got the target node like this
TreeListNode node = tr.FindNodeByKeyID(key_id);
node.Visible = false;
but not hiding the nodes

Comment: Did you get any exception ??